# Controlling hover speed in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have written jquery code to show description if I hover on a hyperlink. But I donot know how to control the speed of the hover, so that i can show the description slowly.Can anyone please suggest me how to do this.

Thanks

Comment: which animation method are you using if any?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.fadeIn()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/)/[`.fadeOut()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/) or [`.animate({ opacity: 'toggle' })`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/), for example:

```
$(".class").hover(function() {
  $(this).next('.description').fadeIn(); //or .fadeIn(2000) for 2 seconds
}, function() {
  $(this).next('.description').fadeOut();
});
```

[You can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/c5Pqm/), or the shorter [`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) version:

```
$(".class").hover(function() {
  $(this).next('.description').animate({ opacity: 'toggle' })
});
```

[You can try that here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/c5Pqm/1/), in the code above you can add a duration as the next parameter to any of these, without it the default is 400ms.